# Soundex search with like operator is not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Soundex search with like operator is not working in SQL Server

```
DECLARE @FirstNameToBeSearch VARCHAR(50) = 'Ronald'

select *
from table
where Country = 'US' + ' and (Firstname like ''' + @FirstNameToBeSearch + '%'' or DIFFERENCE (Firstname,''' + @FirstNameToBeSearch + ''') in (4))';
```

Comment: You are using `difference()` not `soundex()` and your code has no `like`.  I'm confused.

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. What happens when you run this code? Why is that wrong? What is the input data and desired result? What bad result do you get instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
where Country = 'US' + ' and (Firstname like ''' + @FirstNameToBeSearch + '%'' or DIFFERENCE (Firstname,''' + @FirstNameToBeSearch + ''') in (4))';
```

Is wrong, it checks if Country equals the 75 char long string :
**"US and (Firstname like 'Ronald%' or DIFFERENCE (Firstname,'Ronald') in (4))"**

What you want is something like

```
select *
from table
where Country = 'US' and 
(Firstname like @FirstNameToBeSearch + '%'
or DIFFERENCE (Firstname, @FirstNameToBeSearch) in (4));
```

Comment: To be clearer, you could call the `+` "concatenated with" or "followed by", instead of "and".